# Add a check box to interact with sales_order table magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

I'm still new in Magento2. I need to add a checkbox named "Do you want to ship all items at once?"(if there are multiple items) underneath the Shipping Method section. I know in the `sales_order` table has a field name called "**can_ship_partially**", however, it is not exposed in the front end. So my goal is this:

1. If the customer checks the box, it should write to the quote or remember it somewhere else.
2. When the customer placed the order, the value "**can_ship_partially**" should reflect accordingly.

Thanks a lot in advance.